# Why the Simple tag in django is not working?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

I have made a custom tag to set up a flag in my code (for logic).
I have used [link](https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-custom-template-tags-and-filters/) as a reference to set up flag.

Here is the code of my custom tag:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def update_variable(value):
    data = value
    return str(data)
```

My app directory:

```
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── database_consistency.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templatetags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── vars.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Basiclly I am trying to set up a flag in template:

```
<!--Diamonds:-->
<!--Initialized diamond_flag-->
{% with diamond_flag as False %}
    {% for diamond in item.diamonds.all reversed %}
        {% update_variable False as diamond_flag %}
        {% if forloop.first and diamond.rate != 0 %}
            ...
            <!--Trying to update the flag-->
            {% update_variable "True" as diamond_flag %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if diamond_flag == "True" or diamond_flag == "1" or diamond_flag == 1 or diamond_flag == True  %}
        <td>Working</td> <!--This line is not working, the code never runs-->
        <td>-</td>
    {% endif %}
```

I want the flag value to be True between the code so the following 'if' conditions gets true and the code runs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your templatetags "vars.py" in your template.
Example:

```
    {% load vars %}
    <!--Diamonds:-->
    <!--Initialized diamond_flag-->
```

Seen [here](https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-custom-template-tags-and-filters/)

Comment: I have already loaded vars at the top of the template, else it would have generated error.